# Can you help me to write recursive query for two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I need to write recursive query for finding all child nodes in this tables.

For example i need find all child ExecutorTasks for ParentManagerTaskId = 6

```
ManagerTasks
{
  Id,
  ParentExecutorTaskId
}

ExecutorTasks
{
  Id,
  ParentManagerTaskId
}



;WITH query AS 
 (
  SELECT et.Id,et.ParentManagerTaskId,mt.ParentExecutorTaskId
  FROM [Planning.ExecutorTasks] et
  left outer join [Planning.ManagerTasks] mt on et.ParentManagerTaskId=mt.Id
  WHERE mt.Id = 6
  UNION ALL      
  SELECT q.Id, q.ParentManagerTaskId,et.Id
  FROM [Planning.ExecutorTasks] et 
   JOIN query q ON et.Id = q.Id   
  )
  SELECT  *
  FROM query
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What's your RDBMS? In case of `Oracle` have a look at `Start With` (specifies root of the hierarchicy) and `Connect By` (rule how to get children). You may want to add `no cylces` as well

Comment: If you are using MS SQL Server, you need CTE for recursion (https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/).

Comment: @DmitryBychenko MS SQL Server

Comment: @user3044918: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+recursive-query)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name true, but that does not make my statement less valid.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i understand that i need recursive query, but my query does not work good

Comment: @user3044918: which query? You haven't shown us any query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i update question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is a little misleading since you have 2 tables that are related against each other and you only want to display records from one. This means you have to do 2 joins on the recursive part to get the children of the related entity.

Try with the following:

```
;WITH Recursion AS
(
    -- Anchor
    SELECT
        ExecutorTaskId = E.Id,
        RecursionLevel = 0
    FROM
        [Planning.ExecutorTasks] AS E
    WHERE
        E.ParentManagerTaskId = 6

    UNION ALL

    -- Further childs
    SELECT
        ExecutorTaskId = E.Id,
        RecursionLevel = R.RecursionLevel + 1
    FROM
        Recursion AS R
        INNER JOIN [Planning.ManagerTasks] AS M ON R.ExecutorTaskId = M.ParentExecutorTaskId
        INNER JOIN [Planning.ExecutorTasks] AS E ON M.Id = E.ParentManagerTaskId
)
SELECT
    R.RecursionLevel,
    R.ExecutorTaskId
FROM
    Recursion AS R
ORDER BY
    R.RecursionLevel,
    R.ExecutorTaskId
```

I can't test if you don't supply example values, expected outcome and table's DDL.